# How to implement actionlistener for a grid of buttons in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am developing a whack-a-mole game in java. I am creating a 10*10 grid of buttons. However I am not being able to access the id of the clicked button in the actionlistener. Here is the code I have so far.

```
    String buttonID;
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            buttonID = Integer.toString(++buttonCount);
            buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
            buttons[i][j].setName(buttonID);
            buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
            buttons[i][j].setDisabledIcon(null);
            buttonPanel.add(buttons[i][j]);
        }
    }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource()==startButton) {
        System.out.println("Game has been started");
    }
    if (ae.getSource() == "34") {  //please see the description below
        System.out.println("Yes I have clicked this button");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Other button is clicked");
    }
}
```

Currently I have just printed a few things. I don't know how to compare the ae.getsource() with the button that was clicked.  I just tried trying to compare it with "34". But when I click the 34th button on the grid it still prints "Other button is clicked".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the buttons `actionCommand` property to uniquely identify each button as per your requirements...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        buttonID = Integer.toString(++buttonCount);
        //...
        buttons[i][j].setActionCommand(String.toString(buttonID));
        //...
    }
}
```

Then in you `actionPerformed` method, simple look up the `actionCommand` property of the `ActionEvent`....

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String cmd = ae.getActionCommand();
    if ("0".equals(cmd)) {
        //...
    } else if ...
```

Equally, you could using your `buttons` array to find the button based on the `ActionEvent`'s source

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Object source = ae.getSource();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (source == (buttons[i][j])) {
                //...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

But that's up to you...

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This just what I wanted to know :)

Comment: I'd probably use `source == buttons[i][j]` in that place because you don't want value equality but reference equality there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the button object, instead of the string. You don't need to keep track of the id or name of the button. Simply loop through all the buttons to figure out the source.

You can push all the *whack-a-mole* buttons in a list, when creating the buttons. And iterate through them, when finding the source.

Use `setActionCommand()` & `getActionCommand()` instead of `setName()` to process the button *whacked*.

```
 for(JButton button : buttonList )
    if (ae.getSource() == button) {
        //Do required tasks.
    }
```